# How do I interrupt a WCF proxy blocked in Connecting state because remote service not running

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've done a fair amount of searching and have not been able to find a solution or an answer to this.  I have a test app I've written to show "the problem".  (I'm open to the idea that this is just the way WCF works and there's nothing I can do about it.)

My test app is a simple WCF service and client with a Visual Studio generated proxy.  I point the proxy at a remote machine that is up, but not running the service.  That point is important.  If the remote machine is not running at all, the WCF call fails right away.

The client app creates an instance of the client proxy class, kicks off a new Task and then attempts to make a call on the service interface, which will block because the service at the other end isn't there.  The background Task sleeps for 5 seconds and then closes the proxy.  I was expecting the other thread to immediately fault when closing the proxy, but it doesn't.  After about 20 seconds from making the initial call, it then faults.

Here is my client code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestConsoleClient.MyTestServiceReference;

namespace TestConsoleClient
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyTestServiceClient client = new MyTestServiceClient();

        // Start new thread and wait a little bit before trying to close connection.
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            LogMessage("Sleeping for 5 seconds ...");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            if (client == null)
            {
                LogMessage("Woke up!  Proxy was closed before waking up.");
                return;
            }

            LogMessage("Woke up!  Attempting to abort connection.");
            LogMessage(string.Format("Channel state before Close: {0}", 
                ((ICommunicationObject)client).State));

            client.Close();
            ((IDisposable)client).Dispose();
            client.Abort();

            // Channel state is Closed, as expected, but blocked thread does not wake up?
            LogMessage(string.Format("Channel state after Abort: {0}",
                ((ICommunicationObject)client).State));

            client = null;
        });

        // Start connecting.
        LogMessage("Starting connection ...");

        try
        {
            LogMessage("Calling MyTestService.DoWork()");
            client.DoWork();  // Timeout is 60 seconds.  State is "Connecting"
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(string.Format("Exception caught: {0}", ex.Message));
            if (client != null)
            {
                client.Abort();
                ((IDisposable) client).Dispose();
                client = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (client != null)
            {
                client.Close();
                client = null;
            }
        }

        LogMessage("Press Enter to exit ...");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void LogMessage(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: [{1}] {2}",
                          DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"),   Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, msg);
    }
}
}
```

And here is the output from my program:

```
01:48:31 PM: [9] Starting connection ...
01:48:31 PM: [9] Calling MyTestService.DoWork()
01:48:31 PM: [10] Sleeping for 5 seconds ...
01:48:36 PM: [10] Woke up!  Attempting to abort connection.
01:48:36 PM: [10] Channel state before Close: Opening
01:48:36 PM: [10] Channel state after Abort: Closed
01:48:54 PM: [9] Exception caught: Could not connect to net.tcp://th-niconevm:80
80/MyTestService. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:22.0573
009. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected par
ty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection fa
iled because connected host has failed to respond 10.10.10.10:8080.
01:48:54 PM: [9] Press Enter to exit ...
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is letting the user interrupt the connect so they can make adjustments if necessary and then try again.  As you can see in the output, the channel goes from the "Opening" state to the "Closed" state afterward, but the service call stays blocked until it times out.  I can certainly work around it, but it seems like there should be a way to interrupt it.

Here's the client app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyTestService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://remotehost:8080/MyTestService" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyTestService" contract="MyTestServiceReference.IMyTestService"
            name="NetTcpBinding_IMyTestService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="remotehost\ClientUser" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What about binding configuration? Espeially receiveTimeout?

Comment: Adding the client app.config to original question ...

Comment: In a Task Action try out passing in explicit timeout for a `Close()` call: `client.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));` so theoretically it should close/raise an exception after max 2 seconds

Comment: I did already try changing the closeTimeout in the app.config to 00:00:01 and it had no effect on the timeout.  I'll try setting it in code explicitly as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, that had no effect either.

Comment: Please keep us updated if found something, I have pretty the same issue which related to callback invocation on failed channel, it stuch for "ReceiveTimeout" interval (I'm using 2minutes whcih works well, perhaps it has minimum limit sor when you are trying to use Nseconds it reset to default 10!)

Comment: Have you tried setting short sendTimeout and handling TimeoutException  while client.DoWork()?

Comment: I did test that just to see if that was the magic timeout and it is, but that is not a valid fix.  I'd just be making guesses as to how long is long enough.  Is there really no way to interrupt the connection attempt?

Comment: You are trying interrupt connect on a failed channel right? If yes - this is what I'm struggling with as well so if found something let you know

Answer (score 0):

You might get more mileage if you generate your proxy class with asynchronous operations, then your code becomes a lot more simple.

```
// Asynchronously call DoWork
MyTestServiceClient client = new MyTestServiceClient();
IAsyncResult iar = client.BeginDoWork(null, null);

// Sleep, dance, do the shopping, whatever
Thread.Sleep(5000);

bool requestCompletedInFiveSeconds = iar.IsCompleted;

// When you're ready, remember to call EndDoWork to tidy up
client.EndDoWork(iar);
client.Close();
```

If that sounds like it might help, read up on the async pattern.  [This MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582) is suprisingly useful and shows several ways to write asynchronous code.

Your problem may actually be that there is no way to cancel a WCF operation in progress; you would have to write your own cancellation mechanism for this.  For example, you won't be able to tell if a request is actually in progress (i.e.: the `DoWork` execution needs to be aborted) or if some network or other machine latency is the holdup.

Comment: I realized pretty quickly that if the app had originally been written with async in mind, this would not be a problem.  Unfortunately, I'm looking at a significant code base based on synchronous WCF calls (bi-directional TCP) and it would be a significant amount of work to modify the framework and the presentation layer that uses it.  It makes me sad, but that's where I am.  To bring up my original question, is there truly no way to interrupt the connection before timeout?  At the native socket layer, closing a socket handle will interrupt any blocked calls.  So, I know it's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, I don't think so.  You need to invoke `DoWork` asynchronously so that you are in control.  Can you flip your code around so that instead of spawning a task to monitor the client, you spawn a task to call `DoWork`?  You can then monitor that task, and if it takes too long kill it off.